# How do you use git completions to show my current git branch on folder change?

Tags: git, bash

Currently, this works, if I start bash from a folder already containing a git project.

```
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[$BPurple\]\u\[$BGreen\]@\[$BCyan\]\h\[$BGreen\]: \[$BBlue\]\w\[$Yellow\]`__git_ps1`\[$Green\] \$ \[$White\]"
```

My problem is that, if I `cd` into a git folder, nothing happens. And then if I start in a git repo, (where (master) does show up, if I `cd` to anywhere else, the (master) still shows up in my prompt.

So, the `PS1` variable isn't updating. how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[$BPurple]\u[$BGreen]@[$BCyan]\h[$BGreen]: [$BBlue]\w[$Yellow]$(__git_ps1)[$Green] \$ [$White]'
```

I simply replaced the double quotes with single quotes, and wrapped the call to `__git_ps1` in  a command substitution. If that doesn't work (I haven't included parameter expansion in my prompt for a while), try

```
PS1="..."'$(__git_ps1)'"..."
```

where the first '...' is everything prior to '__git_ps1', and the second '...' is everything after. Basically, three strings concatenated together, with the first and third in double quotes and the second in single quotes.

Comment: that shows the color variables as the text, instead of changing the actual color =\

Comment: this is what I came up with which kinda works: `PS1="$BPurple\u$BGreen@$BCyan\h$BGreen: $BBlue\w$Yellow '$(__git_ps1)'$Green \$$White"` but now, the cursor is before the prompt. lol

Comment: so, I learned the most from this post, but I never figured out how to also use my color vars =(

Answer (score 0):

try replace double quotes by simple quotes
almost where variables are used

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}'"[$BPurple]\u[$BGreen]@[$BCyan]\h[$BGreen]: [$BBlue]\w[$Yellow]__git_ps1[$Green] \$ [$White]"
```

Comment: I have a simpler prompt, but I use single quotes and command substitution to make sure `__git_ps1` runs each time `PS1` is evaluated: `PS1='\u@\h:\2:$(__git_ps1) \$ '`

Comment: @Nahuel, I copy pasted, and it's invalid syntax. The quotes I think aren't complete. or something. I'm really lost on the syntax for this type of code. =\

Comment: @chepner, how would I add my color vars to that? I like colors =D